# How to send bitcoins without paying or with extreme low fees and without having to proove my identity?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

Of course, I know it’s no longer possible to get a transaction mined without a miner fee since 2011.

It’s for sending from a single address to a single output address. But I have to split the sending in a large amount of transactions.
I only knows about Gdax which pays the transaction fee for the user (thus making sending transaction free), but it requires sending identity document in order to use it.

**This question isn’t about doing it… It’s about getting answer that might explain how to do it without knowing an e‑mail address !**
Other questions aren’t asking this so that concern cannot be answered on other questions !

Comment: This isn’t a service recommendation question because maybe a way in itself exists for solving the problem.

Comment: So you expect to find someone who will pay the fee for you, but not ask who you are?

Comment: @chytrik : No ! the question is outdated. **This question isn’t about doing it… It’s about getting answer that might explain how to do it without knowing an e‑mail address !**  
Other questions aren’t asking this so that concern cannot be answered on other questions ! **And as explained in my question nt paying transaction fees is possible.

Comment: @PieterWuille this is a way to do it which is also the most likely one (I wouldn’t mind using an e‑mail and a password though)… Or an other way would be how to spend less than 0.09 Bitcoins for making something like 1000 transactions or even not paying any fees at all anywhere.

Comment: @user2284570 The obvious answer is to pay the fee. You're asking someone to do it for you.

Comment: @PieterWuille I have to exchange 1 Bitcoin against bank transfers over the counter : I know several peoples willing to do it… But I don’t trust them nor they do trust me… So I need to perform cent by cent exchanging : this means too much money in transfer fees (on their side bank transfers sending is free for the Bitcoin recipient)… Getting the fee payed by someone else is possible : Gdax is the proof. But remember this might not be the only way. This isn’t money laundering though : The other party would have no problem to accept police questions.

Comment: @user2284570 Perhaps you could set up a LN channel with your counterparty, with a capacity equal to the amount of btc you are trying to exchange, and slowly make LN payments to your counterparty as payments are received. There will be a fee to open / close the channel, but that should sum to *much* less than 0.09 btc.

Comment: @chytrik what’s a ʟɴ channel ? Please remember it’s about real Bitcoins (not Bitcoin fork) : the counterparty uses a system where the only thing I can get from him/her is a Bitcoin address and a price (and he/she see an account number). I don’t send any Bitcoins again until I receive the cents matching the satoshis I sent (usually takes a business day for banks).

Comment: @chytrik ???????????

Comment: @user2284570 sorry for the acronym, LN = Lightning Network. It is a protocol that runs on top of bitcoin, and deals with BTC as the base asset. Your counterparty will need to be able to accept LN transactions in order for this to work. If you search 'lightning network' you can learn more about how it works.

Answer (score -1):

By a paper wallet from someone in person and wipe it with CoPay app.

Comment: It can’t be in person… It has to happen over Internet. There are no cryptocurrency users around me living within the range of 1500Km…

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the answer you are looking for, but you can mine ethereum with GPU and exchange it to Bitcoin on Changelly. This is completely anonymous.

Comment: False ! Changelly is a recognized service ! It has helped the police in the past… Whereas in my case you’ll have to find all the different guys to be sure it’s about Cryptocurrency.